# Deleting required field from ArcGIS Diagrammer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, fields-attributes, arcgis-diagrammer

while creating a feature class in ArcGIS Diagrammer I set the field id_feature_class as required and as type= text now I want to change text to integer but I can't it's telling me id_feature_class is required

how can I delete a required field in ArcGIS or change the field type from text to integer?

Comment: Perhaps these posts might help: [Deleting fields](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/deleting-fields.htm#) and [How To: Change the data type for an existing field](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000009835)

Comment: @Joseph I already had a look at theses posts. I can't delete this field because it's required! I looking for a way to change the required status so I could change the data type or even delete the whole field

Comment: Can you expand more what you mean by "required" and what system/app is using it and why it can not be deleted?

Comment: @artwork21 while creating the feature class in ArcGIS Diagrammer I set the field id_feature_class as required and as type= text now I want to change text to integer or serial but I can't it's telling me id_feature_class is required

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include those highly relevant details.

Comment: Is the fc being used in some-sort of production scope where others are actively using it and it can not be swapped out for a new fc with the old data imported?

Comment: @artwork21 I exported the workspace to XML and edited the type but when export the xml from ArcGIS diagrammer I have only the schema without data

Answer (score 2):

According to [Add Field](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-field.htm) tool help:

> Fields set as required are permanent and you will not be able to
>   delete them with future processing. To allow for deletion at a later
>   time set the field to non-required (the default).

I think you can try to make a copy of your feature class to convert required field to non required and then create a new integer field using data from text field.

Please, do the following:

1. Create new short integer field.
2. Right click on the integer field and call `Field calculator`.
3. Check `Python` box
4. Enter this code in field calculator (replace TEXT_FIELD with your field name, see pic for more details):
   `def convert(text):
   try: 
       return int(text)
   except: 
       return -9999`

`convert(!TEXT_FIELD!)`

5. Click `OK`

[image]

Comment: it's working for a new field, what I need is to change de type of the existing field

Comment: @Hchliyah You have to make a copy of you data. This is the only way to do that. You can't alter or delete required fields.

Comment: It will change the schema of my database

Comment: @Hchliyah See update at the top of the answer.